# re-constructing an image using basic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]

I want to re-construct this 2D matrix (represented by *imagesc*) by using a basic function (polynominal or something else) and coefficients. Once I know which kind of basic function is suitable for this particular problem, I will just find the coefficients in least-square fashion.

The problem is I don't know how to do it in 2D and which type of basic function I should try. I did it nicely in 1D using polynomial function by treating the 2D matrix as 1D, column by column. Now I need to think of it as 2D problem and I have no idea how to deal with this.

I've done some searches and seen like B-splines for N dimensions (http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19632-n-dimensional-bsplines) which seems very nice and similar to my problem but I still dont know how to use or see the connection. I played with this package and see that I can re-construct this image with output coefficient. But I can't find where I can find the matrix of basic function. Would you please help? Thank you very much 
Chappi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we can import the image in RGB format (`MxNx3` matrix `Img`; `uintX`), we have dimension vectors `X` and `Y` (`Mx1` and `Nx1`, respectively; `double`) and colormap `CMap`, say in columns `[value,R,G,B]`.

1. Using `CMap` transform the `Img(MxNx3)` into `Data(MxN)` matrix.
2. Combining `Data(MxN)`, `X(Mx1)` and `Y(Nx1)` create `FitData(M.N x 3)` matrix in form of columns `[X(ii),Y(jj),Data(ii,jj)]`.
3. use [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) function or [`cftool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/curvefitting-app.html).